# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on javascript but when I am calling one method i got

```
 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   

Â var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");

jquery.min.js (line 2, col 3)
```

Please check my code below

```
function addSelectedData(orgName,deptValues)
 {
 var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var checkBoxId ="checkbox"+orgName;
 }
in browser console SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
  [Break On This Error]     

Â var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");

  jquery.min.js (line 2, col 3)
```

Any one help me

Comment: @Riturajratan What difference does that make for a syntax error?

Comment: apply breakpoint in your js file in this function

Comment: I'd honestly suspect that `Â` to be in your code but not displayed in your editor. Try opening with a different one, or maybe even a hex editor. You might be able to verify the sources by checking them in Chrome's Developer Tools -> Sources.

Comment: Appears there are [no-break spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in front of each `var` in your snippet. Combined with issues of character encoding for the script (thus the `Â` in the errors), the parser doesn't know what to do with them. Try replacing them with normal spaces.

Comment: I was wondering that character was messing it up, but the presented syntax error is before that and maybe pasted from the debugger output by accident? What browser are you using?

Comment: seems like something messy with your html code..mind posting it anyway

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your jquery.min.js is messed up somehow? I'd try getting downloading it again - you're not even using jQuery in your example code so I don't think that's the problem. jQuery statements begin with `$` or `jQuery`